# how to ensure tensorflow gpu version is in use with docker image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow 2.13 with help of docker file available within tensorflow models/research/object_detection/dockerfiles folder.

The Docker file contents are

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install apt dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    gpg-agent \
    python3-cairocffi \
    protobuf-compiler \
    python3-pil \
    python3-lxml \
    python3-tk \
    python3-opencv \
    libssl-dev \
    software-properties-common \
    wget

WORKDIR /home/tensorflow

## Copy this code (make sure you are under the ../models/research directory)
COPY models/research/. /home/tensorflow/models

# Compile protobuf configs
RUN (cd /home/tensorflow/models/ && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.)
WORKDIR /home/tensorflow/models/

RUN cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py ./
ENV PATH="/home/tensorflow/.local/bin:${PATH}"

RUN python -m pip install -U pip
RUN python -m pip install .

COPY scripts /home/tensorflow/
COPY workspace /home/tensorflow/

#ENTRYPOINT ["python", "object_detection/model_main_tf2.py"]
```

After all due steps the docker image runs. My host machine has GPU GTX 1650. I tried to test if my tensorflow installation is using GPU using test_tf.py as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Here is the output from test_tf.py

```
root@5433479cb167:/home/tensorflow# python3 test_tf.py 
2023-09-07 14:43:50.620651: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.

To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-09-07 14:43:53.994502: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:268] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (34)

Please install GPU version of TF
```

Using docker is critical for my work so I need to figure out a solution. From the message my understanding is TF detects the GPU but is unable to use it . The last message is confusing since the base image in use is `FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`

I started a small dataset training ( 50 images ) and it seems to be using my CPU to full extent. My training loop is stuck with the following message on the console -

```
I0907 14:31:03.622151 140609981511424 api.py:460] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(128, 128), (64, 64), (32, 32), (16, 16), (8, 8)]
I0907 14:31:10.580329 140609981511424 api.py:460] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(128, 128), (64, 64), (32, 32), (16, 16), (8, 8)]
I0907 14:31:16.743497 140609981511424 api.py:460] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(128, 128), (64, 64), (32, 32), (16, 16), (8, 8)]
I0907 14:31:23.568284 140609981511424 api.py:460] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(128, 128), (64, 64), (32, 32), (16, 16), (8, 8)]
```

Prior to this run my training loop had crashed with the same 4 msgs on console and I had to reduce my batch size which allows the training to now continue. But I have no loss messages on console yet.

Please suggest any steps I can take to address / resolve these issues.

Update # after about an hour my training loop produced loss statement and that confirms all is well with CPU based training

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 100 per-step time 30.199s
I0907 15:21:21.773339 140617841817408 model_lib_v2.py:705] Step 100 per-step time 30.199s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.16712503,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.101843126,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.29896417,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.56793237,
 'learning_rate': 0.0141663505}
I0907 15:21:21.820583 140617841817408 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.16712503,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.101843126,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.29896417,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.56793237,
 'learning_rate': 0.0141663505}
```

Still I am looking for a solution to my GPU woes.

Comment: Have you tried `len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`?

Comment: ``` 2023-09-07 19:15:07.746589: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:268] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (34)
0
``` this was the output

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53341#issuecomment-1166532019

Comment: @Innat I presume all the steps are to be executed / addressed on the host rather then within docker instance ?

Comment: @Innat I ran the steps documented verbatim and no luck yet. have gone through now multiple iterations of reinstall / update / reboot for cuda and cuda toolkit and cuda container toolkit. Still on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the --gpus tag when running the container as said in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#gpus)?

> The --gpus flag allows you to access NVIDIA GPU resources. First you need to install the nvidia-container-runtime.
> To use --gpus, specify which GPUs (or all) to use. If you provide no value, Docker uses all available GPUs. The example below exposes all available GPUs.
>
> ```
> $ docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35532621)